# Expanding only one column in a QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I have this QGridLayout:

[image]

and when I have the value of the file name and source name I want to add them in the `label1` and `label2` expanding only the second column for be enough to read all the string..

some advice for doing it in an easy way?

Comment: You could set fixed width for your labels on the left. Would that work?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know a priori the size of the string i will set (it depends on the file selected from user).. I can calculate the number of character and calculate a new with but it depends on the font used (and i'm planning to change it..) is there no automatic way to say: "hei label, get a fixed with for show all the string"?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. I thought your problem was that both columns got resized when you added the file name to the second column. It seems now that you are looking to expand the second column to a specific size, to be just enough wide to show it's contents. Am i right?

Comment: yes you are right, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via `QSizePolicy` class. Use QLabel's method `setSizePolicy()` to set horizontal and vertical behavior. In your case, you need to set horizontal policy of QLabels in first column to `QSizePolicy::Maximum`, so it would take only the space it needs for itself; and if you want `label1` and `label2` to expand and take all the space available, use `QSizePolicy::Expanding`

Docs - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum

Also, consider adding stretch to columns - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch

Comment: I've just found that I can do it from Qt Designer tool as well, nice!