# PyQtGraph : how to change size (height and width) of graph in a ScrollArea

Tags: python, height, size, width, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to plot graph in a scroll area but I've no idea how to change the size of my graphs. Here is an example of what I have:

[image]

As you can see, in my ScrollArea (in Red) which as the size I want, I have a graph (well, in reallity I have more graphs and I want to see more then one (at least two) in this area).

So, I want the height of my graph (A) to be smaller and the width of my graph (B) to be expanding. Somine can help me ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your plot is inside a layout with the "Hide EMG" button. The widget holding that layout must be resized to fit the scroll area. You'll need to provide a code sample if you want more help than that..

Also consider using pg.MultiPlotWidget, which already provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Lukes comment: A PlotWidget, which is probably what we see there, is a QGraphicsView, which is a QWidget. This is layed out using Qt. I'd recommend you to play a bit with Qt Designer to get an intuition on how the layouting works.

Another resource would be: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

For your explicit problem, if you do not want to get into Qt layouting, you could use QWidget.setMinimumHeight and QWidget.setMaximumHeight to confine the widget vertically. For the horizontal part, that totally depends on what you are doing there. If that was a grid layout, I'd refer to e.g.: [Expanding only one column in a QGridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836447/expanding-only-one-column-in-a-qgridlayout)